# Access 2007 - LostFocus Event

Tags: ms-access, vba

On a form I have a Command button.  After the user clicks the button I want to disable the button so it can't be clicked again.  I know that you can't disable a control while it still has the focus.  So I created this event procedure:

```
Sub Command1_LostFocus()
   Me.Command1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

After I clicked the command button, and then tabbed to another control, I expected the above Sub to run.  But I get the error message "You can't disable a control while it has the focus".  I'm surprised because I thought that when the event procedure was executed Command1 had lost the focus.

Any suggestions on how I can disable a Command button after clicking it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the focus to another control:

```
Me!SomeControl.SetFocus
Me!Command1.Enabled = False
```

And do name your controls something meaningful.